# Trying to email a table created in PHP using SQL values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email, wamp

I have a web-based sign out sheet that displays a list of currently signed out assets (it does this by pulling the variables from an SQL table) I wan to take the same output and send it in an email but every time I try I either get resource id#4 or a blank output. For reasons of confidentiality I can't put up the source code for the mail aspect as its for a client. The below works fine at displaying on the main site. The environment is using WAMP any info would be appropriated.

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "helpdesk", "Password" )or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("loaner")or die("cannot select DB");

$table=mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM signout");

echo "
<div id='status'> <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border=''>
<tr>
<th>Equipment Currently Out</th>
<th>By Who</th>
<th>Return Date</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($table))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Equip'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['User'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Return Date'] . "</td>";

}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table></div>";
echo "</table></div>";
```

Comment: You have not shown where you are trying to actually mail anything?  Where does your error occur?  Basically what you need to do is simply output the HTML to a variable that represents the body of your email and then mail it.

Comment: Also, you need a production environment to test emails as they don't work locally (WAMP) unless you install some neccesary  packages

Comment: replace echo, with assignment to a variable and mail that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the line breaks used with $table aren't necessary, I simply left them there to make it easier for you to see what's going on.

```
mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'helpdesk', 'Password' ) or die('cannot connect');
mysql_select_db('loaner')or die('cannot select DB');

$results = mysql_query('SELECT *  FROM signout');

/**
 * Store the HTML in a variable
 */
$table = "<div id='status'>
<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border=''>
    <tr>
        <th>Equipment Currently Out</th>
        <th>By Who</th>
        <th>Return Date</th>
    </tr>";
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($results) ) {
        $table .= "<tr>";
        $table .= "<td>" . $row['Equip'] . "</td>";
        $table .= "<td>" . $row['User'] . "</td>";
        $table .= "<td>" . $row['Return Date'] . "</td>";
    }
    $table .= "
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>";

/**
 *  Mail the HTML
 */
$body = 'Blah blah blah '.$table.' blah blah blah';
mail($to, $from, $subject, $body);
```